# Assigning the interrupts using _PRT table

Tags: linux-kernel, pci, interrupt

I am facing an issue where function 1 of the PCI device is unable to receive interrupts. I would like to understand how interrupts (legacy INTx) are assigned during Linux bootup based on the PRT table shared by the ACPI BIOS. Specifically, I would like to know how lspci lists those IRQs. Please help me with this. Here is an example: `_PRT` and its bus ranges from the SSDT table.

Here is the EX: _PRT and its bus ranges from SSDT table.

```
       Device (PCI3)
        {
            Name (_ADR, 0x00030000)  // _ADR: Address
            Name (_PRT, Package (0x04)  // _PRT: PCI Routing Table
            {
                Package (0x04)
                {
                    0x0000FFFF, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x0000002B
                }, 

                Package (0x04)
                {
                    0x0000FFFF, 
                    0x01, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x0000002E
                }, 

                Package (0x04)
                {
                    0x0000FFFF, 
                    0x02, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x0000002C
                }, 

                Package (0x04)
                {
                    0x0000FFFF, 
                    0x03, 
                    0x00, 
                    0x0000002D
                }
            })
        }

        Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate ()  // _CRS: Current Resource Settings
        {
            WordBusNumber (ResourceProducer, MinFixed, MaxFixed, PosDecode,
                0x0000,             // Granularity
                0x0023,             // Range Minimum
                0x0030,             // Range Maximum
                0x0000,             // Translation Offset
                0x000E,             // Length
```